# Logger service not found in prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

My setup is :

```
<PackageReference Include="Prism.DryIoc.Extensions" Version="7.2.0.1054" />
<PackageReference Include="Prism.Forms.Extended" Version="7.2.0.1054" />
<PackageReference Include="Shiny.Prism" Version="7.2.0.1054" />
```

```
 protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
     {
         containerRegistry.RegisterServices(services => 
            {
                services.AddLogging();
             }
      }
```

and when i try to get service to assign to property as below :

```
` Logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<AgentBase>>(); `
```

This error happens  :

```
`No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Hyperledger.Aries.Agents.AgentBase]' has been registered.`
```

is there any missing config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project Dryioc is the main container that prism use for Di but my objects are completely depend on Microsoft DI, also some of class must registered from internal access modifier.

Replacing DryIOC with Microsoft Di not recommended by prism  team, but there is an extension for combining  .

finally after combining them and some change in dryioc setting for internal class registration, it worked  .

Also error was solved after Host Builder correct initialization.

Thankyou

Comment: `my objects are completely depend on Microsoft DI` you better have a very good reason for this... this sounds like an exceptionally bad design decision.

Comment: This dependency is a must because of nugget (for some functionality in application ),
it use builder pattern to register services and also have  IHostedService to automatic start of some services during host builder startup.

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

@habib  not sure how host Builder caused this error, as according to error Logger is not getting resolved.  As you are using Shiny.Prism, you can use ShinyStartup to register ILogger. You can register Logger as open generic using:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
```

Or, you can use Delegate Registration from Prism container Extension, if you need more control over how ILogger is getting resolved [Delegate Registration](https://prismplugins.com/registerdelegates/)

P.S can you share how this is linked to Host Builder and your implementation of it to solve it